# Calculating volatility forecast errors - how to obtain "actual volatility" for comparison?

Tags: econometrics, replication

I have to replicate [Liu & Morley (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10690-009-9086-4) on Polish data. They compare different methods of forecasting volatility in terms of Mean Absolute Error and other metrics. They use Hang Seng Index.

What I don't understand is where do they take "actual volatility" from to compute these errors? They claim to use a formula

$$MAE = \frac{1}{\tau}\sum^{T+\tau}_{t=T+1}|h_t-s_t^2|,$$

where $\tau$ is the number of forecasted periods, $h_i$ is obtained from GARCH and $s_i^2$ is this "actual volatility".

If I had to forecast rates of return, I could calculate ex post errors with no problem because rates of return is what I have in raw data to compare forecasted values to. But volatility?

Liu, W., & Morley, B. (2009). Volatility forecasting in the hang seng index using the GARCH approach. Asia-Pacific Financial Markets, 16(1), 51-63.

Comment: it's usually something like $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{t} (r_i - \bar{r})^2}{t-1}$ where $r$ is the return but the window length used and how they obtain $\bar{r}$ matters so you should probably contact the authors of the paper.